# Data Cleaning(Flagging) Dead Sensor

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large timeseries(pandas dataframe) of windspeed (10min average) which contains error data (dead sensor). How can it be flagged automatically. I was trying with moving average.
Some other approach other then moving average is much appreciated. I have attached the sample data image below.

[image]

Comment: You did not attach the data. Also share the work you have done (aka code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to deal with this problem. I will first pass to differences:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
n = 200
y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(n))

y[100:120] = 2
y[150:160] = 0

ts = pd.Series(y)
ts.diff().plot();
```

[image]

The next step is to find how long are the strikes of consecutive zeros.

```
def getZeroStrikeLen(x):
    """ Accept a boolean array only
    """
    res = np.diff(np.where(np.concatenate(([x[0]],
                                            x[:-1] != x[1:],
                                           [True])))[0])[::2]
    return res

vec = ts.diff().values == 0
out = getZeroStrikeLen(vec)
```

Now if `len(out)>0` you can conclude that there is a problem. If you want to go one step further you can have a look to [this](https://minimizeregret.com/post/2017/10/22/detection-abnormal-zero-sequences-count-time-series/). It is in R but it's not that hard to replicate in Python.